# Unable to compile Varnish 2.1 under SUSE 10.3

Tags: installation, varnish, make

I just cloned the latest varnish 2.1 from git-repository. All the dependencies listed on the website have been installed. I run the following commands:

```
./autogen.sh -> works fine
./configure -> works fine too
```

But

```
make -> fails
```

with the following error:

```
make[2]: Entering directory `/tmp/Varnish-Cache-2.1/bin/varnishd'
if gcc -std=gnu99 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I../.. -I../../include   -
DVARNISH_STATE_DIR='"/usr/local/var/varnish"' -g -O2 -MT varnishd-instance.o -MD -MP -
MF ".deps/varnishd-instance.Tpo" -c -o varnishd-instance.o `test -f 'instance.c' ||  
echo './'`instance.c; \
then mv -f ".deps/varnishd-instance.Tpo" ".deps/varnishd-instance.Po"; else rm -f     
".deps/varnishd-instance.Tpo"; exit 1; fi

instance.c:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘.’ token
instance.c:1:35: warning: no newline at end of file
make[2]: *** [varnishd-instance.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/Varnish-Cache-2.1/bin/varnishd'
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/Varnish-Cache-2.1/bin'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

I'm building it on the fairly old SUSE 10.3; don't ask why. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment I don't understand what I have done but it works after replacing the content of

bin/varnishd/instance.c

(which was containing just the path to lib/libvarnishapi/instance.c without any include)

by the content of

lib/libvarnishapi/instance.c

after doing that the make completed successfully